# pre trained model for optical flow images for human activity recognition

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm working on Human Activity Recognition where I'm using a Two-Stream Network. For the Temporal Stream (Optical Flow as an input) i was training my model from scratch and it was taking a lot of resources and time. I decided to use transfer learning by using pretrained model in Keras Applications but every model in the keras application uses 3 channel input shape where as optical flow is 1 channel image.
Can anyone guide me how can i use pretrained model to fit my temporal stream model which uses optical flow images as an input?

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the architecture of the pre-trained model, because it has learned by the same architecture. However, you can transform your 1 channel data to 3 channels data and then feed it to the network. There are lots of ways to do it.

For example, one way is converting grayscale image to RGB, using `tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb()`:

```
data_1channel = tf.constant([[[1.0], [2.0], [3.0]]])
print(data_1channel.shape)   #(1,3,1)

data_3channel = tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb(data_1channel)
print(data_3channel.shape)   #(1,3,3)
```

Or you may use `tf.concat()` to repeat the image 3 times as layers:

```
data_1channel = tf.constant([[[1.0], [2.0], [3.0]]])
print(data_1channel.shape) #(1,3,1)

data_3channel = tf.concat([data_1channel,data_1channel,data_1channel],axis=2)
print(data_3channel.shape) #(1,3,3)
```